# Set Margins without the Geometry Package

Tags: margins

I am using an irregular (for LaTex) paper size, but common for book manufacturing. The right/left margins I get are about 1/3rd too narrow. How can I change them without using the geometry package? Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\paperwidth=4.25in
\paperheight=6.75in
\pdfpagewidth=4.25in
\pdfpageheight=6.75in
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I am familiar with the scrbook package as well as memoir, but I have to use the book package and can't use the geometry package.

Also, the 12 point font size shows up as an "unused global option". So, to get that font size, should I use the extfontsizes package or??

Comment: What about going the other way round: Tell us which important feature the bookest class provides and give an MWE, and maybe somebody here can give a hint how to do exactly this with e.g. scrbook class. I'm asking, because bookest is old and not updated and KOMA-Script comes with really many features.

Comment: The chapter formatting is particularly nice, I think. The title page format as well. It uses most standard \book class commands, but apparently there's a conflict with \geometry.

Comment: The `book` class surely understands `12pt` and is compatible with `geometry`. Without seeing what class you're using, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Is 'it` `bookest`? If so, you need to use the commands explained in its documentation, I suppose, and not those which might work with `book`. Note that there are other page layout packages you can use with `book` e.g. `typearea`, `zwpagelayout` etc. See http://ctan.org/topic/geometry.

Comment: Note that `bookest` ***requires*** `geometry`. That means that you ought ***only*** to change the page layout dimensions using the interface provided by `geometry` else its calculations will probably come out wrong and the results are likely not to be what you desire or expect. (Except that obviously it makes sense to use `bookest`'s package options in this case where applicable since these just set the dimensions using `geometry` anyway.)

Comment: For example, you can just say `\geometry{paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=6.75in, marginparwidth=0pt, marginparsep=0pt}` to set the page and layout dimensions after loading the class. 12pt is not supported by the class, however. As it is, you get a lot of bad boxes. 12pt would make this worse although there are obviously other things you can do to improve things.

Comment: cfr answered the question in the comments but I don't see how I can mark the comment as a correct answer. This does not appear to be in the Stackexchange user manual.

Comment: @cfr Apparently your comments were helpful, wanna write an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B It seems too vague for an answer but there it is ;).

Comment: @user26732 The best thing to do in this case is to leave a comment asking the person to turn their comment into an answer which you can accept and/or upvote and/or whatever. Putting an `@` before `cfr` would have 'pinged' me so I would have known to do this. [It is not always obvious, as in this case, whether something will be helpful or not. So it is quite common to leave suggestions like this in comments and turn them into answers on request.] Glad the suggestions helped, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bookest` and are unable or unwilling to switch to a newer class or package, you should use its facilities to set the page layout dimensions where possible. You can supplement these with a call to `geometry` if necessary. `bookest` ***requires*** `geometry` itself so you do not need a `\usepackage{}`. You can just say e.g. `\geometry{paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=6.75in, marginparwidth=0pt, marginparsep=0pt}` to set the page and layout dimensions after loading the class. You ought ***not*** set the page dimensions directly at all since this will confuse `geometry`'s calculations (since it won't know what you've done) and is likely to give unexpected and undesirable results.

`12pt` is not supported by `bookest`. Since you already get a lot of bad boxes with a smaller point size, 12pt would make things worse (although there are obviously other things you could do to improve things).

If you are willing and able to use another class, you have more options. For example, `book` is compatible with a number of different page layout packages including not just `geometry`, but also e.g. `typearea` and `zwpagelayout`. Or a package such as the Koma-script book-type class can be used with its page layout facilities. (`typearea` is from Koma.) `memoir` is a further possibility. Some of these classes provide extended font size options. All support 12pt.

It is hard to give more specific advice without knowing which class you are using.

Comment: If I could modify scrbook to yield the bookest style, I would.

Comment: @user26732 The KOMA-classes are full of features and options. I bet you can get the style of bookest, but you need to tell us, what exactely you are after.

Comment: I'll make it a separate question.